# Elasticsearch dynamic filter by (price * currency convert rate)

Tags: elasticsearch

User can create a new entity with the price. Prices can be in different currencies(EUR, USD...), so we can get real price by multiply (price*convert_rate).

What I'm trying to do is to filter the records by price, depending on the currency and amount selected by the frontend user (EUR or USD).

Problem is that rates change frequently so i cannot update rate in every document.

Is there a way to filter by array(with rate_id => convert_rate), or dynamically import convert_rate by currency_id in query? Something like this:

```
    {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc[\"price\"].value * convert_rate > 5"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edited:**

Every product have currency_id. By currency_id I want to find convert_rate, and than multiply it with the price.

Currency rates can be either in other document or in array.

Perhaps this will clarify what I need to do

```
    "products" :    {
        "properties" : {
            "id" : {
                 "type" : "integer"
             },
        "currency_id" : {
             "type" : "integer"
        },
        "price" : {
              "type" : "double"
        }
    }
}




{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc[\"price\"].value  > convert_rate",
          "params" : {
               "convert_rate" : **get.convert_rate.where.currency_id == doc[\"currency_id\"].value**
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you found any solution for the problem please share @pusic

Answer (score 0):

Look at custom parameters - You can pass enything from the query to the script

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-script-query.html

Comment: If You only support limited currencies, then You can pass a map of convert rates instead on one rate ...